# Upper bound for gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

Is there a tight upper bound for
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1+a+b}{2}\right)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, that is in terms of a product of a function of $a$ and a function of $b$?

For integers and half-integers, the gamma function aligns nicely with factorials and so when  and  are both even or both odd, an upper bound is $(\frac{+}{2})!\sqrt{\pi}$, and when their parities differ, an upper bound is $\lfloor\frac{+}{2}\rfloor!$. But I want a bound where I don't have to consider a sum of  and , but rather something where I can consider  and  separately.

Comment: What do you know about the $\Gamma$ function ? Basic properties are useful.

Comment: When $a$ and $b$ are both even or both odd, I know the value is exactly $\lfloor \frac{a+b}{2} \rfloor ! \sqrt(\pi)$, and when their parities differ, it would be $\lfloor \frac{a+b}{2} \rfloor !$. But I want a bound where I don't have to consider a sum of $a$ and $b$, but rather something where I can consider $a$ and $b$ separately.

Comment: You should add those attempts to the orginal post, then. Give more context.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: The log convexity of gamma and the [Bohr–Mollerup_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr–Mollerup_theorem) should help you for the product of $\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)$ (set $t=\frac 12$).